# Probability of 9 people going into 3 rooms with 4,3,2 people respectively if the room can and cannot be differentiated

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

What is the probability of 9 people going into 3 rooms with 4,3,2 people respectively if the rooms can and cannot be differentiated?

I would like to verify my thinking logic on this question.

For the case where the room can be differentiated, I take the sample space to be $3^{9}$, which is the number of ways the 9 people can go inside the 3 rooms. If we would like to arrange such that the first room has 4 person, second room 3 person, and third room 2 person respectively, then there are $9\choose{3}$$6\choose{4}$$2\choose{2}$ ways to do this. Dividing this by $3^{9}$ gives us $0.064$.

The second case where we don't know which room has 4, 3,2 respectively is where I am unsure of my answer. I think we just need to multiply$9\choose{3}$$6\choose{4}$$2\choose{2}$ by $3!$, is this correct? This gives us $0.384$.

Comment: Your $\dfrac{{9\choose3}{6\choose4}{2\choose2}}{3^9}$ answer is the probability that $3$ go into the first room, $4$ go into the second room and $2$ go into the third room if each person independently chooses a room with equal probability. For $4,3,2$ rather than $3,4,2$, it would be $\dfrac{{9\choose4}{5\choose3}{2\choose2}}{3^9}$, but this is the same value.  As there are $3!$ possible patterns like this, $\dfrac{3!{9\choose4}{5\choose3}{2\choose2}}{3^9}$ would be the probability for $4$ in a room, $3$ in another room and $2$ in the remaining room, without caring which room is which.

Comment: Such a probability problem is unaffected by whether the rooms are distinguishable.  So, the answers to both parts must be identical.

Comment: May I ask you to clarify why the answers to both part are the same if you don't mind? As I find that there should be more answer if the rooms are distinguishable like in @Henry answer. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Suggestion: write $\frac{9!}{4!3!2!}$ instead of the product of binomial coefficients. It makes clear directly that these products coincide.

Comment: I do not understand your question. (123)(456)(789) and (465)(312)(789) are different arrangements if if have 3-3-3 rooms and the rooms can be ditinguished but are the same arrangements if they can't be distinguished. Can you give an example for the 2-3-4-rooms situation? If (12)(345)(6789) is an arrangement what is an arrangement of these persons that is the same arrangement if we differentiate between the rooms but is a different arrangement if we do not differentiate between the rooms?

Answer (score 0):

Chancing on this question, I see that there are conflicting answers, conflicting views in comments, and that no answer has been accepted ! So I am posting in the hope that the question gets closed and doesn't confuse users who chance on it. !

- Assuming that each room has at least a capacity of $4$ and is equally likely to be occupied, the denominator for computing probability is $3^9$ over which there is little dispute, the problem is about the numerator.
- The multinomial coefficient $\dbinom{n}{n_1.n_2,n_3,...} \equiv\dfrac{n!}{n_1!n_2!n_3!...}, n_i\geq 0, \Sigma n_i=n$
  distributes distinct objects to distinct boxes, $n_i$ to box $i$, not to **any** box, so although, say, $\dfrac{9!}{4!3!2!} = \dfrac{9!}{3!2!4!}$ they are different distributions for distinct objects in distinct boxes.
- Since *people* have identities (as is normal !), with distinct boxes, the numerator has to be multiplied by $3!$ to count all possible distributions and so the probability will correspondingly increase.
- A clear parallel is from the game Yahtzee where a die ($D6$) is thrown five times. A distribution of, say, $2-1-1-1$ of a kind is not just $\dbinom{6}{2,1,1,1,0,0}$ but $\dbinom{6}{2,1,1,1,0,0}\dbinom{5}{1,3}$

Comment: This agrees with Henry's comment about multiplying the numerator by $3!$

Comment: you deleted your answer to [Number of ways of distributing white and black balls into bowls](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4863718/11206). I was not able to comment to a deleted answer therefore I edited your deleted answer. I hope that you can use this and undelete your answer because it shows an additional way to solve the problem.

Comment: @miracle173: My solution was for distinguishable bowls. For identical bowls, OP has given a long solution, and Rezha has given an elegant solution. I do not see the point of giving such a long solution to the identical bowl version when a much shorter and elegant answer already exists. I am reverting to my original answer except for adding one set that I missed, and deleting it. If you want to borrow the table, you may, and post an answer in your name.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this is correct. When the rooms cannot be differentiated, the answer shouldn't simply be $\binom {9}{3} \binom {6}{4} \binom {2}{2}$ divided by $3^9$, because you're assuming that the rooms are distinguishable. For example, you're counting $2, 2, 5$ and $5, 2, 2$ as distinct cases. To clarify, the reasoning behind your sample space being $3^9$ is because there are 3 rooms to put the first person in, 3 rooms to put the second person in, etc., but if the rooms are indistinguishable, it doesn't matter which room you're being put in to, just the people you're put with. Instead, the denominator is not that simple, while for the case of distinguishable rooms, I think you're indeed correct. I will edit my answer soon enough.

Yes, I believe that changing whether the rooms are distinguishable will not change the answer. Both the numerator and denominator are multiplied by $3!$.

Comment: I think that changing the order will still retain the answer, as it would be $9\choose{4}$$5\choose{3}$$2\choose{2}$, same answer. Correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score -1):

The probabilities will be different depending on whether the rooms are distinguishable or not.

**Case $\mathbf{1}$ - Distinguishable**

The total number of ways in which the people can occupy $3$ rooms (no restrictions on the number of people in each room) would be $3^9$.

Given that exactly $4$ people should be in the first room (say, A), $3$ in the second room (B) and $2$ in the third (C), the number of ways would be ${9 \choose 4} \times {5 \choose 3}$.$^*$

So, the required probability equals $\dfrac{{9 \choose 4} \times {5 \choose 3}}{3^9}$.

$^*$ In the question you have stated "...going into 3 rooms with 4,3,2 people respectively...". I am interpreting this as $4$ in the first room, $3$ in the second room, and $2$ in the third (when the rooms are distinguishable).

**Case $\mathbf{2}$ - Indistinguishable**

This time, the total number of ways in which the $9$ people can occupy $3$ rooms (indistinguishable) would be different from $3^9$. That's because every configuration in this case, would give $3$ (if two rooms are empty) or $6$ (in all other cases) configurations for the first case.

For example, the following six configurations we counted as distinct previously will be considered the same in this case. [$a, b ...i \;$ represent the $9$ people and the rooms are in the order $A \,|\, B \,|\, C$]

$$ abc \;|\; def \;|\; ghi \;\;\;\;\;\; abc \;|\; ghi \;|\; def$$
$$ def \;|\; abc \;|\; ghi \;\;\;\;\;\; def \;|\; ghi \;|\; abc$$
$$ ghi \;|\; abc \;|\; def \;\;\;\;\;\; ghi \;|\; def \;|\; abc$$

Whereas the following $3$ would be counted as one in case of indistinguishable rooms.

$$\begin{align*}
&abcdefghi \; | \;\;\;\;\;\;-\;\;\;\;\;\;\; | \;\;\;\;\;-\;\;\;\;\; \\[0.2cm]
& \;\;\;\;\;\;-\;\;\;\;\;\;| \;abcdefghi \; | \;\;\;\;\;-\;\;\;\;\;\;\; \\[0.2cm]
& \;\;\;\;\;\;-\;\;\;\;\;\; |  \;\;\;\;\;\;-\;\;\;\;\;\;\; | \;abcdefghi \\
\end{align*}$$

The number of ways for the favorable case ($4 | 3 | 2$) remains the same because what counted as $1$ configuration in the first case counts as $1$ here too.

Here's one example.

$$ abcd \;|\; efg \;|\; hi$$

Remember, we restricted $4$-people group to room A, so there couldn't be a variant of this configuration that would have to be compensated in this case.

Answer (score -1):

If we distinguish the rooms, the answer is $\binom94\binom53/3^9$.

We stop distinguishing the rooms now. The number of ways in which $9$ people can occupy $3$ indistinguishable rooms is $(3^9+3)/3!$ since almost all configurations are counted $3!$ times. But if two rooms are empty then such configuration is counted only $3$ times.

We can calculate this number in a different way: $S(9,3)+S(9,2)+S(9,1)$, where $S(n,k)$ is [the Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

The number of ways to choose the groups of $4$, $3$ and $2$ is still calculated the same way: $\binom94\binom53$. So the answer is

$$\frac{\binom94\cdot\binom53 \cdot 3!}{3^9+3}.$$